# Toggle Window visibility by deactivating it using a button in other window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem when toggling a window's visibility. The original project used animation, but here I simplified that for switching opacity.

Showing a window using a button works perfectly. Hiding a window by deactivating it works perfectly too.

The problem is when I am trying to hide a window using a button. It looks like first it deactivates, changes state, then toggle button revives click event, sees that window is hidden and shows that again.

Here are my .xaml.cs files:
MainWindow.xaml - it has only Button hooked to events below:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Window _window;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _window = new HideWindow();
        _window.Opacity = 0.5;
        _window.Show();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_window.Opacity == 1)
        {
            _window.Opacity = 0.5;
        }
        else
        {
            _window.Opacity = 1;
            _window.Activate();
        }
    }
}
```

HideWindow.xaml - it's empty:

```
public partial class HideWindow: Window
{
    public HideWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnDeactivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        Opacity = 0.5;
    }
}
```

How can I toggle window visibility using a button and by deactivating the window at the same time? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would first try to prove out that it is in fact the button animation that is causing the window to show again.  Instead of immediately putting that opacity login directly in `ButtonBase_OnClick`, start a timer that fires that logic after say 500ms or something like that.  If the window stays hidden you know your theory was right and you can go from there.

Comment: It's proved. In my project I was using something like this and it worked fine. Obviously - I cannot use it in production.

Comment: So I see in a previous [deleted] answer you're using a view model, are you using any specific framework like Caliburn or anything like that?

Comment: No. This is our internal framework supported by MEF.